# Django (dojango) FieldRegex not being passed

Tags: python, django, dojo, dijit.form

I know there is not much on stackoverflow on dojango, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Dojango describes RegexField as follows:

```
class RegexField(DojoFieldMixin, fields.RegexField):
    widget = widgets.ValidationTextInput
    js_regex = None # we additionally have to define a custom javascript regexp, because the python one is not compatible to javascript

    def __init__(self, js_regex=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.js_regex = js_regex
        super(RegexField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And I am using it as so in my forms.py:

```
post_code = RegexField(js_regex = '[A-Z]{1,2}\d[A-Z\d]? \d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}')
# &
post_code = RegexField(attrs={'js_regex': '[A-Z]{1,2}\d[A-Z\d]? \d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}'})
```

Unfortunately these both give me:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

If I use the following:

```
post_code = RegexField(regex = '[A-Z]{1,2}\d[A-Z\d]? \d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}')
```

I get the following HTML:

```
<input name="post_code" required="true" promptMessage="" type="text" id="id_post_code" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" />
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After three days of beavering away I fould that you need to send `regex` and `js_regex`, though `regex` is not used:

```
post_code = RegexField(
    regex='',
    required = True,
    widget=ValidationTextInput(
        attrs={
            'invalid': 'Post Code in incorrect format',
            'regExp': '[A-Z]{1,2}\d[A-Z\d]? \d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}'
        }
    )
)
```

[Oh yeah! and you also need to declare the widget as a `ValidationTextInput`]

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to `super().__init__` call. If `fields.RegexField` is standard Django `RegexField`, then it requires `regex` keyword argument, as documented. Since you don't pass it, you get `TypeError`. If it's supposed to be the same as `js_regex`, then pass it along in the super call.

```
def __init__(self, js_regex, *args, **kwargs):
    self.js_regex = js_regex
    super(RegexField, self).__init__(regex, *args, **kwargs)
```